# Why does my pandas dataframe not sort with sort_values?

Tags: python, pandas

I tried sorting my dataframe by multiple columns where I would like 1 column to descend.
I have used the following code to try to do so:

```py
officeSuppliesDf.sort_values(
    by=['Region', 'Total'],
    ascending = [True, False],
    inplace = True,
)
```

Where officeSuppliesDf is my dataframe with data read from a csv file and The Total column should be descending.

However when I print my datadrame I get the result where Region is sorted, however, The Total column seems random.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Picture of result after sort attempt]

Comment: it looks like your total column might contain text data. it is sorted lexicographically rather than by numerical value. try `df['Total'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total'])`

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the data type of the 'Total' column? Is it perhaps a string and not a float?

You can check the datatypes using the .dtypes:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html

Try:

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I indeed had not checked for this option. Do all the values read in by pd.read_csv have the type string?

Answer (score 0):

You have a Comma `,` after `inplace=True`.  You should remove this.

Try this:

```py
officeSuppliesDf.sort_values( ['Region', 'Total'],
                               ascending = [True, False],
                               inplace = True)
```